# determinacion de subespacios

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Determine si los subconjuntos indicados, son subespacios vectoriales del espacio vectorial V dado, con las operaciones
usuales de adici´on y multiplicaci´on por escalar sobre el cuerpo K. Justifique sus respuestas.
(b) V := P(R), K := R . S := {p ∈ V : ∃ a , b ∈ R : ∀ x ∈ R : p(x) = (a + 1) x
2 + b (x + 1)} .

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: Please write in english